# How do i arrange the print out of my programs loop horizontally without repetitions

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to make a program that prints out all perfect integers up to 10000, I've been able to get my program to do that but i can't seem to be able to arrange the print out properly;i would like to make it display like this:

6: 1 2 3

28: 1 2 4 7 14

496: 1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248

8128: 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 127 254 508 1016 2032 4064

but i'm currently getting this:

8128:4064

8128:2032

8128:1016

8128:508

8128:254

8128:127

8128:64

8128:32

8128:16

8128:8

8128:4

8128:2

8128:1

ive tried everything i could think of right now but cant seem to get it right :C,

(ps: it displays the output vertically for each perfect integer :c ) pls help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void perfect(int number)
{

int DivTotal = 0, Div;
//string


    for (int halfNum = number / 2; halfNum >= 1; halfNum--)
    {

        Div = number % halfNum;

        if (Div == 0)
        DivTotal += halfNum;

    }



    if (DivTotal == number)
    {
        for (int halfNum = number / 2; halfNum >= 1; halfNum--)
        {

            Div = number % halfNum;

            if (Div == 0)
            cout<< number << ":"<< halfNum<<endl;
            //cout<<endl;

        }

    }


}



int main()
{

    cout << "Perfect numbers between 1 and 10000 are:" << endl;

    for (int count = 1; count <= 10000; count++)
    {
         perfect(count);
        // cout << perfect<< ":" << endl;
    }

 system("Pause");
 }
```

Comment: You might want to include the definition of a "perfect integer" in the question

Comment: You should probably move the `cout<< number << ":"` part of the output to before the for-loop, so it doesn't print each time you find a new factor.

Comment: but the for loop is where is the variables are located, it wont be able to call them for a print out if i do that( or do you mean the second for loop)?

Comment: Having fixed Bo's issue, you should count up from 2 up to number/2 to get the output starting from 1 up to latest divisor (2: 1 *always* is a divisor, so you do not need to count it; furtherly, you have to count only up to sqrt(number) to get all divisors...)

Answer (score 1):

Fine-tuned variant of so far given answer:

```
if (DivTotal == number)
{
    // needs to be moved out of loop for not being printed with every number
    // additionally, 1 is always a divisor, so we can add it right here:
    std::cout << number << ": 1";

    for(int i = 2; i * i <= number; ++i)  // counting up to have order right!
                 //^^^^^ until sqrt only...
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
            std::cout << ", " << i;
                        //^ with or without comma...
    } 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: so basically my solution has been staring me in the face all along lol, wow, i feel so disappointed in myself

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this helps

```
if (DivTotal == number)
{
    char toPrint[100];
    char toAdd[10];
    sprintf(toPrint,"%d:",number);
    for (int halfNum = number / 2; halfNum >= 1; halfNum--)
    {

        Div = number % halfNum;

        if (Div == 0)
        {
             sprintf(toAdd," %d ",halfNum);
             strcat(toPrint,toAdd);
        }
    }
    cout<< toPrint<<endl;
    //cout<<endl;
}
```

To use sprintf and strcat remeber to include stdio.h

Comment: it says "strcat" is not declared after i included the stdio.h

Comment: Your `C`-like code will produce buffer overruns if the number has more than 8 digits.  Use `C++` solutions such as `std::string`, so that you do not need to specify the buffer size..

Comment: i'm sorry strcat is in string.h

Comment: Thanks so much guys,  @A.Ortogni your fix works like magic XD

Comment: I'm glad to help you